# Wrong download directory for Selenium Firefox Geckodriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've been trying to get Selenium to download a file to a specific folder, but to no avail.

Here is my current driver setup with lots of simultaneous attempts to influence the download directory:

```
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options:0x00007f94374c0bd0 @debugger_address=nil, 
@options={
  :browser_name=>"firefox",
  :args=>[],
  :prefs=>{
    "download.folderList"=>2,
    "download.dir"=>"./downloads",
    "download.directory_upgrade"=>true,
    "download.prompt_for_download"=>false,
    "download.default_directory"=>"./downloads",
    "plugins.plugins_disabled"=>"Chrome PDF Viewer", 
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"=>"application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv"
  }
},
@profile=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x00007f94374c0e28 @model=nil, 
@additional_prefs={
  "browser.download.folderList"=>2, 
  "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting"=>false, 
  "browser.download.downloadDir"=>"./downloads", 
  "browser.download.dir"=>"./downloads",
  "browser.download.directory_upgrade"=>true, 
  "browser.download.prompt_for_download"=>false, 
  "browser.download.default_directory"=>"./downloads"
}, @extensions={}>>
```

I have tried:

- Download directory (I'm using Mac):

  - /lib/downloads
  - downloads
  - ./downloads
- Lots of combinations of the above attempts to set the download directory.

I went through the [selenium-webdriver docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Firefox/Options) and [Mozilla Webdriver docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver), but I cannot find references to set the download directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom directory path has to be **absolute**, formed as shown:

- On Mac, ~Downloads folder would be `/Users/[me]/Downloads`.
- In Rails, say you want to put the downloads in `lib/custom_downloads`, the directory specified should be `Dir.pwd + '/lib/custom_downloads'`.

The code that worked for me:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.download.dir'] = Dir.pwd + '/forecastsdir'
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel')
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile, args: ['-headless'])
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, options: options
```

Many thanks to @Rajagopalan (+1) for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know whether it works.

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new(ENV['APPDATA'] + '\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3deyh6ub.default-release')
profile['browser.download.dir'] = custom_download_dir
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, options: options
```

and check out this path `Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3deyh6ub.default-release` and see what's the folder name and give the folder name accordingly and it will work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. First I'm on Mac so the profile folder for me is `/Users/[me]/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/l7kfmhse.default-1524776181722`. I put that in and it said `No such file or directory ...` for that folder.

Comment: If I remove the folder entirely (just do Firefox::Profile.new), it says `Unable to create a driver with parameters: {:profile=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x00007fd861d5db80 @model=nil, @additional_prefs={"browser.download.dir"=>"forecastsdir", "browser.download.folderList"=>2}, @extensions={}>} (ArgumentError)`

Comment: @sscirrus I have edited the code. Can you try now?"

Comment: The new code runs but it doesn't download any file. I had to add `profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel')` so it would accept the download. However, the file is going to ~/Downloads.

Comment: I just figured it out. Posting an answer. Thank you so much for your help, @Rajagopalan! +1